# How to use GSL library in C for diagonalization of a Hermitian Matrix?

Tags: c, gsl

I have basic knowledge about C programming language. I know loop structure, array and control statements. Suddenly I need to know that how to diagonalize a Hermitian matrix using the **GSL library** in **C language**. Installation of GSL is not a problem. But I would like to know how to use it for this specific purpose. I am reading GSL manual these days but a concise and precise answer would be highly appreciated?

Comment: On which operating system, and with which compiler? Did you read the documentation, it has a [Using the GSL library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Using-the-library.html#Using-the-library) chapter!

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking at section [15.2 Complex Hermitian Matrices](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Complex-Hermitian-Matrices.html#Complex-Hermitian-Matrices).

To compute the eigenvalues you'll first want to look here:

```
gsl_eigen_herm_workspace * gsl_eigen_herm_alloc (const size_t n)
```

> This function allocates a workspace for computing eigenvalues of
>   n-by-n complex hermitian matrices. The size of the workspace is O(3n).

Then look at:

```
int gsl_eigen_herm (gsl_matrix_complex * A, gsl_vector * eval, gsl_eigen_herm_workspace * w)
```

> This function computes the eigenvalues of the complex hermitian matrix
>   A. Additional workspace of the appropriate size must be provided in w.
>   The diagonal and lower triangular part of A are destroyed during the
>   computation, but the strict upper triangular part is not referenced.
>   The imaginary parts of the diagonal are assumed to be zero and are not
>   referenced. The eigenvalues are stored in the vector eval and are
>   unordered.

Eigenvalues *and* Eigenvectors can be found using:

```
gsl_eigen_hermv_workspace * gsl_eigen_hermv_alloc (const size_t n)

int gsl_eigen_hermv (gsl_matrix_complex * A, gsl_vector * eval, gsl_matrix_complex * evec, gsl_eigen_hermv_workspace * w)
```